# If all the solutions of $\frac{dy}{dt}=A(t)y$ are bounded, then all the solutions of $\frac{dz}{dt}=[A(t)+B(t)]z$ are bounded

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

In the book by Richard Bellman, *Stability theory of differential equations*

**Theorem 6 (p.43)**

> If all the solutions of $\frac{dy}{dt}=A(t)y$ are bounded, then all
>   the solutions of $\frac{dz}{dt}=[A(t)+B(t)]z$ are bounded, provided
>   that:
>
> - (a),$\int_{t_0}^{\infty}\left \|B(t)  \right \|\mathrm{d}t<\infty$
> - (b),$\lim_{t \to \infty}\int_{t_0}^{t}TrA(t_1)\mathrm{d}t_1>-\infty$
>
> or, in particular, that
>
> - (b') $Tr(A)=0$.
>
> Condition (b') is relevant to the important equation:
>   $$\boxed{\ddot{u}+a(t)u=0}$$ which is equivalent to a two-dimensional
>   system satisfying (b')

I don't understand "*Condition (b') is relevant to the important equation:
$$\boxed{\ddot{u}+a(t)u=0}$$ which is equivalent to a two-dimensional
system satisfying (b')*".

I don't see the equation $\ddot{u}+a(t)u=0$ makes sense with the theorem above, if you understand this theorem, you can explain to me? anyone? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$A(t)$ and $B(t)$ are matrices, not just ordinary functions.  To turn a second-order differential equation into a first-order differential equation with matrices, let $v$ be the column vector $\left[\begin{array}{cc} u\\ \dot{u}\end{array}\right]$.  The derivative of that is $\left[\begin{array}{c}\dot{u}\\ \ddot{u}\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{cc} 0&1\\-a(t)&0\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}u\\ \dot{u}\end{array}\right] =A(t)v$

Comment: Yes, I see. Thanks **Michael**. And since $A(t)$ as above, we have $tr(A)=0+0=0$.